# Returning passed argument as object

Tags: javascript

```
function Hello(name) {

    function changeName(newName) {
       name = newName;
   }

    return {
      changeName: changeName,
      name: name
    };
}

var o=Hello("Martin");

o.name;   // "Martin"

o.changeName("Marc");

o.name;   // "Martin"
```

From the above code it's clear that `changeName` is not changing the `name` property.

1.Why is that?

2.What is `changeName` actually changing?

Comment: can you call `changeName` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the function `Hello` with `"Martin"`, the value of the variable `name` declared as an argument for the function `Hello` is assigned the value of `"Martin"`.

When you return the object that has the property `name` set to the value of `name` passed into the function, the string is copied. Now `o.name` has its own string which is separate from the value of the variable `name` in the `Hello` function. Any change to `name` would not impact the value which is now set on the object's property. This can be demonstrated as follows:

```
var name = "Martin";
var o = {
  name: name
};
name = "Marc";
console.log(o.name); // Martin
console.log(name); // Marc
```

This almost addresses your first question, but the full answer to your first question requires the answer to your second question. When you declare `changeName` in the `Hello` function it creates a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) which inherits the variable `name`, meaning that any change to the variable `name` will be reflected whenever `name` is used elsewhere (one example is in other closures). This is hard to see in your code since the only place that `name` is used after `Hello` runs is in `changeName`, but you can see in the example below what I mean:

```
function Hello(name) {
  function changeName(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }

  function seeName() {
    return name;
  }

  return {
    changeName: changeName,
    seeName: seeName,
    name: name
  };
}

var o = Hello("Martin");

console.log(o.name); // "Martin"

o.changeName("Marc");

console.log(o.name); // "Martin"

console.log(o.seeName()); // "Marc"
```

These two factors make it so that your `changeName` method doesn't have the effect you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify that you want to change the property of that object using the "this", else the "name" will be just a local variable...

try:

```
 function changeName(newName) {
       this.name = newName;
   }
```

Comment: i'm not looking to "correct" the code but just rather understand why it behaves that way.

Comment: @dylan1994, you must specify that you want to change the property of that object using the "this", else the "name" will be just a local variable ...

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeName(newName) {
     name = newName;
}
```

is changing the local variable `name` (the argument), not the property of the object returned. Because string is immutable, when you do:

```
var str = "str";
var str2 = str;
```

str and str2 are different objects. If you modify `str`, `str2` won't be affected.

You can do the following:

```
function Hello(name) {

    function changeName(newName) {
       obj.name = newName;
    }

    var obj = {
      changeName: changeName,
      name: name
    };

    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `this` keyword while you returning name from `changeName()` method.

```
function Hello(name) {

    function changeName(newName) {
       this.name = newName;
   }

    return {
      changeName: changeName,
      name: name
    };
}

var o=Hello("Martin");

console.log(o.name);   // "Martin"

o.changeName("Marc");

console.log(o.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to demystify [PASSING BY VALUE OR BY REFERENCE](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass):

> When passing in a primitive type variable like a string or a number, the value is passed in by value. This means that any changes to that variable while in the function are completely separate from anything that happens outside the function.